# Vue3 internationalization with I18n and script setup (vite)

Tags: internationalization, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to internationalize my Vue3 (with Vite setup) project with `@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n` and im using `<script setup>`

I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: i18n.global is undefined` but everthing seems correct. I've even tried original code from offical document which you can find [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/lazy.html#lazy-loading)

No matter what i do, Vue or i18n cannot find `global` property of i18n.

So my i18n.js is like this:

```
import { nextTick } from "vue";
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import axios from "axios";
import tr from "../src/locales/tr.json";
import en from "../src/locales/en.json";

export const SUPPORT_LOCALES = ["tr", "en"];

export function setupI18n(options = { locale: "tr" }) {
  const i18n = createI18n(options);
  setI18nLanguage(i18n, options.locale);
  return i18n;
}

export function setI18nLanguage(i18n, locale) {
  if (i18n.mode === "legacy") {
    i18n.global.locale = locale;
  } else {
    i18n.global.locale.value = locale;
  }

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Language"] = locale;

  document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("lang", locale);
}

  export async function loadLocaleMessages(i18n, locale) {

  const messages = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `./locales/${locale}.json`
  );

  // set locale and locale message
  i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages.default);

  return nextTick();
}

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "tr",
  fallbackLocale: "tr",
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: {
    tr,
    en,
  },
});
export default i18n;
```

component.vue

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
  import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
  import { SUPPORT_LOCALES, setupI18n, setI18nLanguage, loadLocaleMessages } from '../../i18n.js'

  const { locale } = useI18n() // same as `useI18n({ useScope: 'global' })`
  const currentLocale = ref(locale.value)

  function selectLanguage(language) {
    // locale.value = language.target.value
    loadLocaleMessages()
  }

  onBeforeMount(() => {
    setI18nLanguage(currentLocale.value)
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What works for me is adding `import i18n from '@/i18n';` to the script setup in the vue component. Then I can access the `i18n.global` object.

Comment: But im getting this error in `i18n.js`. I tried your solution but it didnt work.

Comment: O, okay. Your setup differs from mine. Is it giving a line where it throws the error? Looking at your code, you might need to call `const i18n = setupI18n();` in your component.

Comment: Problem is not component, im getting this error directly from i18n.js. I uploaded screenshot of error for you. https://ibb.co/VqHrHFH

Comment: I see. If you look at the error you can see that it is caused in the setup function of SelectLanguage.vue, calling the setI18nLanguage function in i18n.js. The setI18nLanguage function require the i18n instance as the first argument and the locale as the second argument. Now you are providing it only with the locale when you call the function: `setI18nLanguage(currentLocale.value)`. This should be `setI18nLanguage(i18n, currentLocale.value)`, therefore you need the i18n instance in your vue component. You can access that as described in my earlier comments.