# Using Vue-i18n with script setup and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vue-script-setup

***EDIT:*** 
The reason I could not reference `$t(key: string)` in the `<script setup>`, is that I had not declared it as a variable [like mentioned in the docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#message-translation) and pointed out in a comment by *Michal Levý* (thanks!).
All I needed to do was add `const { t } = useI18n();` and boom! It works, by referencing *t* like this:

```
var message = computed(() => t(TranslationKeys.Message))
```

Hopefully more poor souls with the same issue as me find this post, 'cause I sure didn't know what I was doing wrong.
Original post beneath.

---

***ORIGINAL:*** 
Trying out the new `<script setup/>` method for Vue3 in conjunction with *TypeScript* and *Vue-I18n*.
I have previously used *I18n* with *Vue3* and *composition*-style, without too much hassle, like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { TranslationKey } from "@/i18n/translationkeys";
import { Vue } from "vue-class-component";

export default class Navbar extends Vue{  
  data() {
      return {
        workAgreement: this.$t(TranslationKey.WorkAgreement),
        documentation: this.$t(TranslationKey.Documentation)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, now when trying to use `$t()` within the script tag, it simply says:

> *Cannot find the name '$t'*.

But still works just fine within the `<template/>` tags. 
As shown above I previously used the `data()` function within the script tag to declare/get variables, but since they've changed how the whole data/setup thing is done, I have a hard time wrapping my head around how it's supposed to be done now.

For clarification:
Within my component `HelloWorld.vue` I have this, which works fine.

```html
<template>
  <h2>{{ $t(TranslationKeys.Message) }}</h2>
  <v-btn @click="changeLanguage">Change language</v-btn>
</template>
```

But also this which has compile errors with `$t()`, getting the "*Cannot find the name '$t'*"-message.

```js
<script setup lang='ts'>
import { LanguageType } from '@/resources/languageTypes';
import { TranslationKeys } from '@/resources/translationKeys';
import { useRootStore } from '@/store/root/rootStore';
import { computed } from 'vue';

var message = computed(() => {$t(TranslationKeys.Message)})
var store = useRootStore();

function changeLanguage() {
  store.SetLanguage(store.GetCurrentLanguage == LanguageType.DK ? LanguageType.EN : LanguageType.DK);
}

</script>
```

I might have missed something somewhere in the documentation, and if that's the case I apologize in advance.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547416/17438890

Answer (score 1):

`$t()` in `<script>` never worked ...you must use `this.$t()` if you are using old Options API

If you want to use i18n inside `setup`, the `useI18n()` API [must be used](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#message-translation)

Comment: What I needed was the `const { t } = useI18n();` mentioned in the docs, thanks for the pointer on that 
However, I just want to mention that evidently this seems to be a recurring challenge, from the looks of the discussion thread on github.
Like others I deemed it weird that I could not reference it directly in the `<script>` as well, and though after looking in the dosc the first time around that I had to use the instance of `i18n` from my `main.ts` and not the `useI18n()` from the plugin itself.