# Vue - Use i18n within the setup script

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-i18n

I need to find a way to use the `$t` of `i18n` within the setup script for my `vue` project

my i18n file looks like this:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from './en';
import es from './es';

const messages = { en, es };

const locales = [
  { code: 'en', name: 'English' },
  { code: 'es', name: 'Español' }
];

const i18n = createI18n({
  locales: locales,
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages,
  silentTranslationWarn: true,
  silentFallbackWarn: true,
})

export default i18n
```

my main js look like this:

```
import i18n from './lang/settings'
const application = createApp({ 
            render: () => h(app, props) 
        })
application.use(i18n)
```

I can perfectly use `$t()` in the template to translate but I have no clue how to access the same method within `<script setup></script>`

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547416

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The i18n resource and the related files need to be placed in the way you have mentioned in your question.

You can use it in this way
I have Added everything in main.ts for better understanding.
you can use it in this way

Main.ts

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  messages: {
    en: {
    sample:{
      item1: 'hello world'
    }
  }} // set locale messages
});
createApp(App).use(router).use(i18n).mount('#app');
```

In your component

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const { t } = useI18n();
let name = t('sample.item1');
</script>
<template>
  {{name}}
</template>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I find it unbelievable that such a simple task is not specified in the official documentation with its own section...

Comment: is there a way to use localePath also in the script setup tag? because useI18n() doesnt have an localePath attribute

Answer (score 14):

For Vue-i18n **version 9**

add `legacy: false` when creating the instance (main.js)

```
const i18n = VueI18n.createI18n({
  legacy: false, // you must set `false`, to use Composition API
  locale: 'ja',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages,
  // other options
})
```

and in your script setup

```
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const { t } = useI18n({ useScope: "global" });

// Something to do here ...

</script>
```

[vue-i18n doc](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#global-scope)

Comment: This worked for me, when the accepted answer didn't work.

Comment: ```legacy: false``` life saver. thanks. this answer has to be correct answer

Comment: @SefaUn YES but it broke my ability to change languages, I have to debug that now.

Comment: @Bw.Kizito I dont have any problem with that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**NUXT3**

Create lang folder in project root:

en-US.js

```
export default {
  readMore: "Read more",
};
```

Follow this for more info: https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/lazy-load-translations

You can import in your component:

```
const { t } = useI18n();
```

And use it:

```
let myElement = {
   text: t('readMore')
}
```