# How can i use I18N-Vue as a prop?

Tags: vue.js, i18next, vue-i18n, vue-props

How can i use I18N-Vue in a prop in Vuejs? I need to translate variables to another language. It is a mistery to me how i can define these things, and also how to give them an id if they are in an array, because they somehow get read from both angles.

Comment: It's likely you can use the `$t` function to do all this. Trying to pass the library as a prop doesn't really make sense.

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76295335/21198448 - don't forget to add lega = false